# Not Able to Add Class Name to Button Component on Rendering in DOM

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know why I am not able to pass class name of `.btn-primary` using

```
<Button styleClass="btn-primary" text='Primary Button' />
```

after running this  I am seeing `${styleClass}` in the element in inspector instead of the class name

[image]

```js
const Button = ({ styleClass, text }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={'btn ${styleClass}'}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
               <div>
                 <Button styleClass="btn-primary" text='Primary Button' />
               </div>
, window.root);
```

```css
body{
padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the `'` characters to back-tick ` ([grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)) characters for string [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) interpolation using `${}`:

```js
const Button = ({ styleClass, text }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={`btn ${styleClass}`}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Button styleClass="btn-primary" text='Primary Button' />
  </div>
, window.root);
```

```css
body{
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="root"></div>
```

Or without string interpolation:

```
const Button = ({ styleClass, text }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={'btn ' + styleClass }
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Hopefully that helps!